# one ViewController goes to another ViewController

Tags: objective-c

I want to implement following GUI on ipad.

when user start my application, I have a ViewController which has button on that, after user touched one button it will go to another View Controller.

My question is how to display a new ViewController in current ViewController.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an `IBAction` in your header and connect your button to this action.

Then in your action, use:

```
/* also add - (IBAction) goToAnotherView: (id) sender; to your header */
- (IBAction) goToAnotherView: (id) sender {

    MySecondViewController *secondView = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    [secondView release];

}
```

Comment: I added the above code in my application but still does not work. Is there other code I need to modify as well?